# I have an error in unity with my script that seems to me all fine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have a C# script to capture an input if clicked on the TextMeshPro Button with the script. It worked for a wile but since a week or a few days there is this one error:

> Assets\FPS\Scripts\Gameplay\Managers\ButtonTEST.cs(11,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using Unity.TextMeshPro;

public class ButtonTEST : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button captureButton; // The button to capture input
public TextMeshProUGUI inputText; // The TextMeshProUGUI component to display captured input

    private bool isCapturingInput = false; // Flag to indicate whether input capture is active
    private string capturedInput = ""; // The captured input string

    private void Start()
    {
        captureButton.onClick.AddListener(ToggleInputCapture);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isCapturingInput)
        {
            if (Input.anyKeyDown)
            {
                // Clear the captured input
                capturedInput = "";

                // Find the first key that was pressed down
                foreach (KeyCode keyCode in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
                {
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode))
                    {
                        // Store the captured input as a string
                        capturedInput = keyCode.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Display the captured input
                inputText.text = "" + capturedInput;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ()
    {
        isCapturingInput = !isCapturingInput;

        // Reset the captured input and display "Input..."
        if (isCapturingInput)
        {
           capturedInput = "";
           inputText.text = "Input...";
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner.

I already tried to ask ChatGPT but the AI only gave me rubbish (like adding the line: "using TMPro" but that line already existed)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Dunno if you looked, but try the following: https://forum.unity.com/threads/the-type-or-namespace-name-textmeshprougui-could-not-be-found.544102/

Comment: have you used asmdefs? are you sure the textmeshpro package is in the game?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line `using Unity.TextMeshPro;` [Error image found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns9SJ.png)